# Access: Creating a Form without Tables

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, frontend

I'm in kind of an odd situation where I'm trying to create a front end Form in Access based on survey questions. What makes this a bit complicated is the Access Database that the survey question answers will be put into is another person's responsibility and incomplete.

What is the best (or is there a best) way to create a front end Form that can then be attached to a database after completion?

Comment: 'Best Practice' is usually to first create the database model (tables/queries), then create the forms, but you can follow @Andre's advice, if this is not possible, That may lead to additional effort if there are major diffs between your test db-model and the production one (e.g you need to create a subform).

Answer (score 1):

- Create sample backend database
- Create table(s) with sample questions/answers in there
- Give sample DB to other person and tell them how to fill it
- Build your form based on the sample tables, using a split database (frontend + backend)
- When the real data is complete, use that one instead of your sample backend.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using a MS Access database for a survey.
- No need to separate the form and the data.
- Keep a copy of the empty database.
- Mail the database to survey responders.
- Responders send the completed database back to you by email.
- Forward the completed databases to the other person who collates the answers.

Comment: This is not an answer to OPs question, as he wants a split db (maybe multi-user in an intranet). And your database is very poor designed (no PK, answers and questions should be separated, a user is missing). Maybe mark this as an alternative suggestion and don't link your ugly db until you improved it (look foe datbase normalisation).

Comment: OK I have unlinked the database. Thanks for your advice.